# Looking up Google Sheets values using sheet id instead of sheet title (Google Drive Rest API V4)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-workspace

Using the Google Sheets REST API V4, and would prefer to use the sheet id instead of sheet title to look up values in a cell. It seems like you can specify the sheet within the spreadsheet using the range, e.g. `Sheet4!A1:Z500`, but not a sheet ID such as `1310487470!A1:Z500`. This is so the query doesn't have to change if someone renames the sheet. Does the Google API support querying by ID?

Current query:

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1SR0DJ4nV5-05EWxjz1OYOWkKFObClmsC0rOowPnMwNE/values/Sheet4!A1:Z500`

Ideal query:

`https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1SR0DJ4nV5-05EWxjz1OYOWkKFObClmsC0rOowPnMwNE/values/1310487470!A1:Z500`

Comment: I have never found how to use GID to A1 notation yet. How about this way? For example, it retrieves both sheetId(GID) and its title using ``sheets.spreadsheets.get``, and creates A1 notation using the title for the GID. The url query is ``https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/sheetID?fields=sheets(properties(sheetId%2Ctitle))``. The scope of ``https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly`` can be used for both APIs. If this will not be helpful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: I just confirmed with GSuite support that there's no supported way. They can see the need for querying by ID and recommended I file a feature request. In the meantime, your workaround seems plausible, thanks @Tanaike!

Comment: If you need the sample script, feel free to tell me. I can prepare it.

Comment: I already implemented it- but if you have time to post your script perhaps it will help someone else here.

Comment: I posted it just now.  I selected GAS as a sample.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sheet ID in Google Sheets API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934537/how-to-use-sheet-id-in-google-sheets-api)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about following sample? I prepared it as a GAS sample. If you use this, please enable Sheet API v4 at API console.

This retrieves data of a sheet in spreadsheet using GID.

1. Retrieves information of sheets in spreadsheet. A JSON data which has keys of GID and values of sheet name is created.
2. Retrieves data from sheet using the JSON.

**Sample script:**

```
function fetch(url){
  return UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
    }
  });
}

function main(){
  // Retrieves information of sheets in spreadsheet. 
  var spreadsheet = "#####";
  var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheet + "?fields=sheets(properties(sheetId%2Ctitle))";
  var sheetdic = {};
  JSON.parse(fetch(url)).sheets.forEach(function(e){
    sheetdic[e.properties.sheetId] = e.properties.title;
  });

  // Retrieves data from sheet using GID.
  var sheet = sheetdic["#####"]; // Imports sheet name using GID.
  var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheet + "/values/" + sheet + "!A1:Z500";
  var results = fetch(url);
}
```