# Accessing values in a Google Sheet using A1 notation with non-latin characters

Tags: rest, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to access the values in a Google Spreadsheet that is localized to Russian. In Russian, Sheet is Лист and so the default sheet names are Лист1 and Лист2, etc.

The method I am using to retrieve values from a specific sheet is to use the spreadsheet values API and A1 notation to limit results to the specific sheet:

/v4/spreadsheets/{spreadsheet-it}/values/Лист1!1:1

However, the Google API returns a 400 bad request. If I manually rename the sheet to use only latin characters (like Sheet1) it works just fine.

But this is too much to ask our users using languages with different alphabets - I'm hoping there is a way I am not seeing in the documentation to access values for a specific sheet using the numeric Sheet ID rather than the sheet title?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use sheet ID in Google Sheets API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52934537/how-to-use-sheet-id-in-google-sheets-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer for question 1:

In my environment, I can confirm that `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]/values/Лист1!1:1` works. And when I saw the response value, `"range": "'Лист1'!A1:Z1"` can be seen. So for example, how about enclosing `Лист1` by the single quotes like `https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]/values/'Лист1'!1:1`?

When the curl command is used, it is as follows.

```
curl \
  "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]/values/%27%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%821%27%211%3A1" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ###"
```

- `%27%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%821%27%211%3A1` is `'Лист1'!1:1`. In this case, the range value is encoded by the URL encode.

  - Also I thought that in your case, the URL encode like above might be required.
- By the way, in my environment, I can confirm that the following curl command also works.

  ```
    curl \
      'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/[SPREADSHEETID]/values/Лист1!1:1' \
      -H 'Authorization: Bearer ###'
  ```

### Answer for question 2:

If you want to retrieve the cell values using the sheet ID, how about the following method? In this case, `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEETID]/gviz/tq?gid=[SHEETID]&range=1:1&tqx=out:csv` is used as the endpoint.

```
curl \
  'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/[SPREADSHEETID]/gviz/tq?gid=[SHEETID]&range=1:1&tqx=out:csv' \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer ###"
```

- When above curl command is run, the value is returned as the CSV format.
- By using the access token, the values can be retrieved without publishing.

### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)
- [Using google query to download parts of a published sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48511747)